# unable to run file as program

Tags: files

I downloaded a file (wich has no extension) and I cant execute it by checking the ´Allow executing file as program' checkbox.

I did chmod +x on the file and now I can run it from the terminal with ./Filename
But I want to be able to run it by just double clicking, when I do this, I get this:
[image]

edit: the file is a 'shared library file'

Comment: When this message appears did you click ok? so it may find a needed software. Because the message tells you that there's no GUI software in your system that can read this file.

Comment: @JoKeR Yes I did, it did not find anything

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve? A shared library is usually a file that other libraries or executable files need. If FTB Launcher stands for a Minecraft mod and you try to install it, use the method described in the documentation of the mod.

Comment: It is a launcher, I am able to tun it through the command line with command ./FTBLauncher_64bit and it runs just fine, I just want to be able to run it by double-clicking.